# Travelling from London to Queenstown, NZ through Sydney airport, will I go through customs/border control?

Tags: visas, transit, australia, working-holiday

I have a working holiday visa for Aus, but I am first flying to NZ to visit friends.

I am a UK Citizen. The flights are all on one ticket.

My transit is through Singapore, Indonesia and then Sydney, Australia airport.

I am only in Sydney about an hour and a half before my flight to Queenstown, NZ.

So I am wondering if my Australian w/h visa will begin from the date I travel through Sydney?

Or will I have to return another time to start it?

Comment: Can you confirm that the flight to and from Sydney are on the same ticket? Given the time between the flights I would guess so, but just to be sure...

Comment: For completeness, what is your citizenship?

Comment: It depends on whether you stay in transit or go through Customs as an arrival. Please update your question to be more specific.

Comment: I am a UK Citizen. The flights are all on one ticket, so I assume I wont be going through customs, however I don't know for sure.

Comment: I think you are going to have to ask the airline whether you will stay airside or not.